# One small luggage and one big on EasyJet?

Tags: luggage, easyjet

I'm flying with EasyJet soon.
My luggage allowance is 2 x 20kg.
I want to take one big item, which is 12kg with no possibility to add more to it. (It's my TV: I'm moving from parents' house to my new place abroad.)

Does anyone have any idea if it would be ok to have bag one of 28kg along with my one of 12kg to make my 40kg or is it strictly  per item rather than per customer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EasyJet's policy is that you have an allowed number of bags and an allowed weight. As long as each bag isn't too heavy, you can distribute the weight between the bags however you wish.

This [FAQ](http://support.easyjet.com/%7Bbdd84180-35a1-11e3-d73f-000000000000%7D) on their site explicitly says you can distribute weight between two bags (when you're allowed to carry two bags); their [baggage allowances page](http://www.easyjet.com/en/planning/baggage) says that an individual bag can't exceed 32kg. So you can take 1x12kg + 1x28kg instead of 2x20kg.

You might have to drop the heavier bag at a different baggage drop but they'll tell you that when you check in.

Answer (score 1):

According to the T&Cs here: http://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions (para 19.4.11) you're not allowed electronic equipment or fragile items in your hold baggage. And presumably your TV is too big to take as hand baggage.
How about buying a used TV at your destination - then at least you know it will support the local transmission standards.

Comment: Nice and very useful find! Just a thought though, it doesn't really answer the question, so it might be better as a comment.

Comment: @DavidMulder: I tried that, but SE wouldn't let me comment on someone else's post as I have not yet collected enough rep on this board.

Comment: @pnuts: OK, the operative word is 'should', but have you seen how the loaders handle stuff? I wouldn't dare put a TV through that, even in its original packaging.